# Need help in gcm in sending notifications when there are multiple logins from a single device

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

For example,there is a user A who logs in initially in my app. I am storing the registration token in my app server when he logs in.So, when he is online,if someone sends him any message,the message reaches the app server and registration token is taken from database for that user and request is sent to GCM server.

Now, the problem is if the user is logged out,I am deleting the registration token from database(this is because my app supports multiple logins).So,when an user is offline,suppose there is one more message coming for that user,there is no registration token in my server.So, the "to" will be empty in the request part to GCM server.

So,how will the offline user get his message when he comes online?Any suggestions...?

My app has login for multiple users and I want every user to get their notification when they come online in any device(Like facebook does) suppose a message was sent to them when they are logged out.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to store a list of pending messages on your app server for users who are offline. Add a method when the user logs on that can poll the server for any pending messages and then send them.

Comment: Okay..how to automatically send messages from server when user logs in?

Comment: When the user signs in, you will have to generate a new token to send to the server, when the server gets a new token for the user, the server can then do the check for pending messages and send them as necessary.

Comment: Presumably you already have a method for sending messages normally. You shouldn't need to do anything different here, just add an extra call to that method for any pending messages when you do your usual login handling.

Comment: Actually,how mine works is that when the sender is sending the message,the message is sent to my app server where the the corresponding people's reg id is picked from the table and the request is sent to GCM server by executing a PHP file. Now, how to automatically execute a PHP file when user logs in? previously, the HTTP request sent by the sender executes the PHP.But now..How to?

Comment: @Brucelet do you mean that we must send HTTP request to get notification from the mobile of the msg receiver?if yes,please tell me how?

Comment: I'm just assuming that your app server can run some code in response to a user logging in (as you are presumably doing something to check their credentials and store authentication data). You could add a method in that code to send extra requests to the GCM server for any pending messages you've stored on your server. If you aren't able to do something like that I'm not sure I can help you.

Comment: I think I got an idea. And how does facebook app does those things? Like the method which you said?

Comment: And what about sending message to topics? I want to know how to use that? How to create our own topic and if we send message to  that,how will all users get the notification from that? In that case,no need of all the above methods ?

Comment: @Brucelet Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: These are all separate issues that are worthy of their own questions, or your own research.